# C# kill single process from multiple instance from the same app

Tags: c#, kill-process

I'm trying to develop an app that will run multiple VLC instances with a custom URL,

The problem is that I want to be able to kill any one of them at a specific time and leave the rest running.

I am only aware of this method which kills all the processes by name

```
public bool CheckIfRunning(string ProcessName)
{
    Process[] p;
    p = Process.GetProcessesByName(ProcessName);
    if (p.Count() > 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

if (CheckIfRunning("vlc") == true)
                    {
                        Process[] workers = Process.GetProcessesByName("vlc");
                        foreach (Process worker in workers)
                        {
                            worker.Kill();
                            worker.WaitForExit();
                            worker.Dispose();
                        }
                    }
```

Now, this method kills all and I only need 1 to kill so is there any way to know which one I need and how to kill this one only?

Comment: Keep track of the ID when you start it and use that to kill it.

Comment: Processes are commonly identified by their respective process id => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.id?view=net-6.0